# Lua Error Loading Limlib2 Library even though it's already installed?

Tags: lua

I have install limlib2 and everything and I've checked the directories to see if it's existent, and limlib2 is there. I compile some lua code that uses

```
    require("limlib2")
```

I receive this error:

> lua: error loading module 'limlib2' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/limlib2.so':
>       dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/limlib2.so, 6): Symbol not found: _luaL_checkint
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/limlib2.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/limlib2.so
>   stack traceback:
>       [C]: in ?
>       [C]: in function 'require'
>       imgpxl.lua:1: in main chunk
>       [C]: in ?

Any help? I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Where did you get `limlib2.so` from? It appears (as per Piglet's comment) to have been built for lua 5.2 but you have installed it for use with lua 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

limlib2 is referencing `_luaL_checkint` which fails in Lua 5.3 as `_luaL_checkint` has been replaced by `_luaL_checkinteger` in Lua 5.2

`_luaL_checkint` is deprecated. Just google for `_luaL_checkint` to find plenty of workarounds.

Checkout this: [Cannot make gunplot on osx yosemite. Undefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667629/cannot-make-gunplot-on-osx-yosemite-undefined-symbols)

imlib2 seems to haven't been updated in over 8 years. So no wonder you're facing problems

Comment: Thanks! Also just a question, I'm finding that i need some #define statements, would I have to edit that in the module (c code) itself?

Comment: yes. the problem is in the c code so you have to fix it there.

Comment: Where is the c code that i can edit, all i seem to have is the library file (.so)

Comment: source should be linked here. It's the authors website. contact him and ask him to update his repository

Comment: I've installed the library using luarocks, would it be possible to fork the repository and edit and then install somehow?